# Снятие роли по команде

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

У меня уже есть команда, которая выдает участникам сервера определенную роль.

Как теперь по еще одной команде снять со всех членов сервера эту роль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [`remove_roles`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#nextcord.Member.remove_roles)

Затем итерируйте список участников

```
@commands.command()
async def remove_role(self, ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.remove_roles(role)

@bot.command()
async def remove_role(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.remove_roles(role)

# без указания роли
@bot.command()
async def remove_role(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='айди роли')
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: Не понимаю, где мне задавать название роли.

Comment: !remove_role @role

Comment: Работает. А я могу прописать роль внутри команды? Чтобы я просто писал команду, а бот убирал роль, например: Doctor. Я пытался через discrod.Role и role, но ничего не выходит

Comment: Да, можно, сделал изменение
p.s. discord: RAINGM#1941

Comment: По id почему-то не работало. Даже ошибки не выдавало. Зато через name сработало. role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Название роли')